# i.i.d. estimation of variance

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, expected-value

Let ${X_i}$ for $i\in N$ be a string i.i.d. with a known expected value of $\mu = E (X_1)$. Investigate the properties
the estimator of the variance given by the formula : $\frac{1}{n} \sum(X_i ^2 - \mu ^2)$ (sum from 1 to n). Have you got some hints?

Comment: What does "investigate ownership the estimator of the variance" mean?

Comment: "Investigate the properties", maybe?

Comment: Yes, sorry  for my mistake.

Comment: One property you could investigate is whether the expected value of the estimator is less than, equal to, or greater than the actual variance.